# Using jQuery UI Autocomplete and Tabs - Clashing of modified CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm currently using jQuery UI tabs that has modified css to reposition the location of the tabs and the look and feel.

I also have jQuery UI Autocomplete the same page. However, using the default jQuery UI css for autocomplete disfigures the appearance of the customised tabs.

I have modified the tabs css to view a higher div, in an attempt to isolate it a little:

```
#MYContainer .ui-state-active a, 
#MYContainer .ui-state-active a:link, 
#MYContainer .ui-state-active a:visited { 
color:transparent;
text-decoration: none; 
background-color:#fff;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
width:11px;
height:11px;
margin-right:05px;
padding:0;
color:transparent;
```

}

However, leaving the original css to handle the UI of the auto complete overrides this.

Any suggestions on how i can have two modified UI components on the same page would be greatly appreciated.

****EDIT*****
This is my HTML for the input that initiates the autocomplete

```
<div id="searchwrapper">
<input title="Title" type="text" id="SearchBox"/>
<button type="button" id="SearchButton">Search</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: It'll take me awhile unfortunately. Currently it's integrated with a content management system that pulls through information from XSLT. If i could somehow grab the entire autocomplete html and umbrella it in another div, i'd probably have more control over it.

Answer (score 0):

Use css selectors to target the tabs only. You may add a wrapper or use precise selector such as > to make it work.

With your HTML maybe I can give you a better example.

Comment: Hi Anys, thanks for responding. I have added my HTML for the auto complete input box. As you can see in my original post, I targeted the tabs with my css. I cannot think of a way to wrapper the autocomplete, as it's in it's own hidden div at the bottom of the DOM (not inside any of my divs)